# CSS Keep all flexbox children elements the same size

Tags: css, flexbox

My code is [shown in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/xcf1e5nd):

```css
#container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 200px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

.child-item {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-basis: 75px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
</div>
```

[image: flexbox grid]

Although, I would like the two items across the bottom to have the same with as the items on the top.

I don't want to float them left and fix their width, this will not work for my arrangement in other resolutions.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, I have replicated your setup with a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/xcf1e5nd/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have 2 ways of doing this:

**flex-grow: 0** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qamethj/))

If you set `flex-grow` to 0 you are telling the items to keep their width; this maximizes the amount of empty space. Using `flex-grow: 1` the items will expand their width to fill as much empty space as possible.

**invisible items** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln4h3c4n/))

Add some invisible items after the normal items with the same flex properties. You will get a left aligned look.

In this solution there will be the same number of items in all visible rows so make sure to add enough invisible items to work properly on larger screens.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: @Igor the first solution looks promising, is there a way to align all of the equally-sized items to the left?

Comment: @TaylorMac the second solution does that, but the fiddle was wrong. Try it now.

Comment: @Igor brilliant idea actually, although I think you'd have to be rather nitpicky to control display: none on the items at different screen resolution. Regardless it seems like this is the best solution, thank you

Comment: IMO flexbox is pretty useless with `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` set to 0. The second solution is good though (just remember to set the invisible items to 0 height so they don't increase the height of their container unnecessarily.)

Comment: invisible is not as bad as it first sounded

Answer (score 11):

I can't reply to Igor's answer to suggest an improvement to his solution, but his fiddle did not work entirely for a responsive layout.

The first solution with `flex-grow: 0;` doesn't stretch the items to fill the containers. The second solution with invisible items works, but expands the height of the container. Removing the top/bottom margins did the trick though.

I edited the jsfiddle, to make it both responsive and fix the container-expanding invisible items, using comments to explain what I changed. It still doesn't work if the container is larger than the row of items though: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2L2o3qh/))

I also made my own simple solution. I was trying to do this myself, and Igor's solution helped immensely. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5j08g4t/))

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
  /*style*/
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
.item {
  flex: 1 0 80px;
  
  /*style*/
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.filler {
  flex: 1 0 80px;
  height: 0px;
  
  /*style*/
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">sm</div>
  <div class="item">medium</div>
  <div class="item">large item</div>
  <div class="item">medium</div>
  <div class="item">medium</div>
  <div class="item">large item</div>
  <div class="item">sm</div>
  <div class="item">sm</div>
  <div class="item">medium</div>
  <div class="item">large item</div>
  <div class="item">medium</div>
  <div class="item">medium</div>
  <div class="item">large item</div>
  <div class="item">sm</div>

  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when there's more than enough room to fit everything on one line the invisible items start taking up space on line 1. Also, this solution makes the justify-content and align-items properties useless, since every row will always be full. Probably not a big deal in many cases, but worth pointing out.

Comment: TL;DR: Use invisible items with 0 height to fill the empty spaces.

Comment: I love this solution but anyone have an idea to fix the problem which @Ajedi32 talk'd about? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o5j08g4t/3/ . Yeah sure  i can still remove these fillers but i want to use it dynamic (as mixin/partial). JavaScript is no solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

you can try set `flex-basis: 50%;` and `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
   flex-basis: 50%;
   flex-grow: 1;
   background: tomato;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the items to stop expanding with `max-width` on the elements ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcf1e5nd/7/)). To get them to left-align, use a different `justify-content` on the wrapper ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcf1e5nd/6/)).

Hope this works! Have only been looking at this in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with max-width is that it restricts the size of all of the boxes.

If you play with the fiddle, you will notice that the boxes adjust their size to fill in the space. By setting max-width, they behave no different from floating elements.

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't realize that was what you meant in your original question :/ I think I know of something else that miiight work but is a very different solution. I'll try to make a JSFiddle of that.

Comment: both jsfiddle solutions set the width of the elements, which is what I wanted to avoid (and let flexbox determine the width). Thank you for your work and let me know if you find out anything else!

Answer (score 2):

Flex basis is limited by min-width and max-width, so in this case, if you set your max-width equal to your flex basis, you will get the desired results.

This also retains your alignment properties--meaning that if you have 5 items in a row with two remaining, the remaining items will still be centered on the page and at the correct size.

```
.container
   @include display-flex
   @include flex-wrap(wrap)
   .item
       @include flex-grow(1)
       @include flex-basis(190px)
       @include max-width(190px)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, a grid layout might be more suitable than Flexbox due to its flexibility in handling complex arrangements.

See the demo for details:

```css
  

#container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    background-color: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

.child-item {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

[For this type of problem, I just use float.](http://jsfiddle.net/wsznqo2b/)

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child-item {
  float: left;
}
```