# Make flexbox prioritise showing more items over the max-width of item

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a row of boxes with a min/max width of 300/400px per box. I want flexbox to show more boxes per row when it can. At widths where it can't fit an equal amount of 300px boxes horizontally then it should show larger 400px boxes to fill the remaining space.

On this example, at a browser width of 929px it shows two 300px boxes where ideally it can fit and should show two 400px boxes

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1260px;

  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 1 300px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;

  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-color: grey;  
}

.profile {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="profile" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGrzGW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
flex: 0 1 300px;
```

You have flex-grow set to 0, so the boxes won't grow to fit the available space.

Change that line to this:

```
flex: 1 1 300px;
```

And your code works as expected. ([View CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPZNrE))

Comment: Doh. Thanks. Can you constrain the width of the second rows boxes? So if the top row are 300px boxes then the bottom row will match that rather than grow to the available 400px width.

Comment: @DanChristian I don't think so. You could set the flex-basis to a percentage based value like `calc(25% - 10px)`, then change that value at certain breakpoints using media queries though.

Comment: @DanChristian Actually, it seems there's an even better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29642790/1157054