# Fit content (100%) depending on number of items in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been struggling to make an image gallery which auto-fits the content (`width: 100%`) depending on the number of items it contains.

Here is what I mean:
Let's assume that this is my gallery:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNMOEz

```
.item {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-width: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

As you scale the browser, since items are set to `float: left` the number of items increase per row.

However then the width of the gallery has gap at the right side of the page since each `.item` is defined to be exactly `75px`.

What I wanted would look closer to this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGWKaP

```
.item {
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
}
```

As you can see items per row fit exactly to the page `width` as item width is defined as percentage instead of a fixed px value. However there are two issues with this one as well, which I want to solve:

1. Item number per row is fixed (20 as in the example). I want item number to be like a "`Math.floor`" value of how many can fit. For instance if the item width is set to be 75 pixels and if the page is 800 pixels width, then item count should be 10 (as 750 pixels is the max. that can be covered by 800 pixels width.) So it should be `width: 10%`
2. There is a gap at the bottom of each row, I have no idea what causes this.

I'm primarily looking for a css-only solution - but a clever and non glitching js is accepted as well.

This is a long post, I hope everything is clear.

Comment: What would you want if there were just two images on the last row? Should they be 50% wide?...otherwise this is pretty hard without JS.

Comment: No, they should continue with the flow. If a single image is 5% of the total page then all of them should be 5%. But I still would love to see your solution. @Paulie_D

Comment: You can get close, with `flexbox`...if you allow the items to grow to match the width (with a starting width of 75px) but the alignment of the remainders is problematical...I'm not sure that it is solvable exactly how you might imagine. http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZGxzmL?editors=110

Comment: Oh...BTW...the gap you mentioned...it's because the images didn't have `display:block`  http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dombaj

Comment: @Paulie_D it's very close indeed! but the last row ruins. yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't solvable with CSS...the block nature of layout just doesn't allow row wrapping **and** shrink-wrapping at the same time.

Comment: Nope...I don't think so. `flexbox` was probably the best CSS option.

Comment: @Paulie_D here is something closer, though maybe you migt want to have a look http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpoKNW still not there as last row does not pass 50px per item

Comment: Well that's just cheating plain and simple..:)  but if it works for you.

Comment: no well it still does not since the last row items does not change scale @Paulie_D

Comment: Modified version of @Paulie_D 's version [combined with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514579/css-keep-all-flexbox-children-elements-the-same-size) using transparent "ghost items" http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNMYKr . Paule_D, feel free to add as an answer it if you want just make sure to credit the other thread.

Comment: @Jan very nice! However I tried this on iphone and it does not work :(

Answer (score 2):

You can view a potential answer in: [Flex - controlling the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224850/flex-controlling-the-last-row/31225680#31225680)

As for your second question:

> 2) There is a gap at the bottom of each row, I have no idea what causes this.

This is caused by an image inside a block. If you add 'vertical-align' top/middle/bottom, then the gap disappears.

Answer (score 0):

A `Flexbox` will be of better use to you. It will allow you to made the adjustments you requested in your post.

See a great tutorial here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
.item {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

or it (if the scrollbar is present):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0px;
}
.item {
  width: 5%;
  height: auto;
  /*border-width: 1px;*/
  float: left;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try this instead, if you desire show all images in a row (really i not understand completely because the english isn't my native language, you should note this for my bad writting, and explain a bit more ¬¬)

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0px;
  width:100%;
}
#wrap {
  display:inline-table;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.item {
  display:table-cell;
  height:10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where is the "depending on number of items" part in this? How is this different than my second link?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand the first issue correctly, i think that "depending on number of items" means per row, the difference is the code clean the gap at the bottom of images between lines. you want show all images in a row?

Comment: Read the question again please

Comment: I update the response, tell me if this is that you want.