# Flex - controlling the last row

Tags: html, css

Here is an issue I'm dealing with. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpoKNW

As you can see last element is a `.fill` class element. If you scale the page slowly you will see that all other items (except the final row items) change size accordingly, however final row is fixed to 50px.

What I want is, all items behaving the same way. Can this be done in css-only?

Comment: Original question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223445/fit-content-100-depending-on-number-of-items-in-a-row?noredirect=1#comment50449502_31223445

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D - it became something else during our ping pong session so I created this thread :]

Comment: It seems you want a grid layout. But flexbox has no grid notions. Items at different flex lines behave independently.

Comment: what would you suggest? @Oriol

Comment: @Zettam Maybe CSS Grid (not sure, I don't know it). But it's not widely supported (I think only IE supports an old version of the spec, and others don't support it at all).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're happy with using percentage widths, then you could use:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.item {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 50px;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .item {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 267px) {
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 125px) {
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

The nice thing here, is that you can define how many items you want per row in different screen widths by using @media queries.

However, for that, **you could just as well avoid using flex**:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .item {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 267px) {
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 125px) {
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could probably even remove 'min-width' from item and make one of the @medias to 250px instead of 267px (not sure why it was misbehaving before).

Comment: Very nice! I like how simple this is, eventhough it's not the answer of the particular question I asked, this might be a good solution for similar cases.

Comment: To be fair, I love this flex cheat sheet: http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/ . It proved to be quick and simple. Thought I'd share it.

As for your problem - I am not aware of any way you could solve this with just HTML and CSS. You will then either have the same row a bit different (e.g. spaces between the last row items being different or them not aligned to the left) or in certain scenarios have some space on the right.

Comment: Someone in another thread I created came up with this solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNMYKr

Comment: I don't know where you're planning to use it, but this avoids creating dummy htmls. However, if this works for you, then go for it, but keep in mind that the number of dummies has to be (n-2), where n is the number of items. Why? Because on bigger resolutions you get the same problematic behaviour you had: http://i.imgur.com/6vLDkDW.jpg . Why (n-2) exactly? This will happen if all n items but 1 won't fit into one line. Therefore the first line is n-1 and the second line already has 1 item - (n-1-1) = (n-2)