# Responsive, dynamic thumbnail gallery: The last row doesn't work

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, zurb-foundation-6

i want to create a responsive thumbnail gallery: http://www.moviesite.de/TEST/MAM/imagewall.html
Everything works, except for the last row:
The images are too big. What can i do, that these images are as big as the images in the rows before?

Thanks

Comment: Using firefox all the images appear to be similar sized and four to a row on large screen with several rows. Using IE11 the images are all thumbnails and in a single row on large screen, then tiny dots and one row with 1 image on medum and then tiny dots and 1 row of 3 images on small.  I think your min-width maybe is not working out,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/min-width

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add** **ghost/filler elements**.

I found a fiddle with a solution for your Problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29642790/4757877).

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: royalblue;
}

.item {
    flex: 1 0 80px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.filler {
    flex: 1 0 80px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0 0.5em; 
    padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">sm</div>
    <div class="item">medium</div>
    <div class="item">large item</div>
    <div class="item">medium</div>
    <div class="item">medium</div>
    <div class="item">large item</div>
    <div class="item">sm</div>
    <div class="item">sm</div>
    <div class="item">medium</div>
    <div class="item">large item</div>
    <div class="item">medium</div>
    <div class="item">medium</div>
    <div class="item">large item</div>
    <div class="item">sm</div>

    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```